# print string that has a . when the length of the last character is 2

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 4 lines in a file `yahoo.txt`

```
a.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.com
yahoo.co.uk
```

I print the last char

```
awk -F. '{print $NF}' yahoo.txt
```

That give me

```
com
uk
com
uk
```

Example in the above example output should be

```
a.yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.co.uk
```

My another try was not useful (`grep uk`), I can't grep the `uk` because the actual file has a lot of text...

I want to print a line that has a `.` when the length of the last character is `2`

Comment: With sed: `sed '/\...$/!d' file`

Comment: whith grep: `grep '\...$' file`

Comment: With perl: `perl -ne '/\...$/ && print' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk and a regex:

```
awk '/\...$/' file
```

Output:

```
a.yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.co.uk
```

Comment: For this kind of purpose, `sed` (your first choice) is a lot quicker than any of `grep`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`!

Comment: Being curious I compared the proposed solutions presented on this page using 1000000 records of OP's data and: By far the fastest was grep, next came awk, then sed and the slowest was perl. On my laptop grep spent 0.006s and the others about 0.150s, 0.250s and 0.450s (average of three runs).

Answer (score 1):

You might use `length` function for this task, let `file.txt` content be

```
a.yahoo.com
a.yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.com
yahoo.co.uk
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}length($NF)==2' file.txt
```

output

```
a.yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.co.uk
```

Explanation: `length` return number of characters.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*